# how can I access media player in media list player?

Tags: java, video, media-player, vlc, vlcj

I'm using Java and VLCJ library (VLC 3.X.Y). I created a media list player and a media player object.

medialistplayer.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);

I need to get media player from media player list. How can I access media player in media list player?

Comment: Please add more details on what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming vlcj 4.x:

```
MediaPlayer mp = mediaListPlayer.mediaPlayer().mediaPlayer()
```

But, you already have a reference to the mediaPlayer you originally set, so you could just keep it somewhere yourself.

*Side note: the duplicate "mediaPlayer()" above is unfortunate, but was done for reasons of consistency with the rest of the API.*

You don't need to create your own media player, one will be created for you automatically if you want.